# Can someone review this Windows command before I run it

Tags: command-line, file-transfer

I am wanting to copy my `.gitignore` file into all projects in my directory.

I do not want to overwrite the file if a folder already has it (so flagging to request confirmation `/-y`)

```
for /d %a in (C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\) do copy /-y C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\FolderContainingFileIWantCopied\.gitignore %a
```

Can someone confirm this is accurate before I run it, and let me know what I should expect (there are over 200 folders, with approximately 10-20 having a .gitignore file currently.

While I was comfortable in the command line in the 90's, I am nervous about running a command that could touch so many projects

Comment: There are no wild-cards in the `in` clause, so the `for` loop will iterate only once.

Comment: If you want to test a complex loop command, run the inner loop with `echo` in front of the command to verify the command that it would run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For top-level subfolders only:

If you want to stick to command-line:

```
for /d %A in ("C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\*") do (if not exist "%A\file.gitignore" copy /y "C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\FolderContainingFileIWantCopied\file.gitignore" "%A\file.gitignore")
```

I generally prefer using variables where I can so I also wrote it out in batch - and also using `if not exist` in place of the copy `/-y` prompt to make it more automated, but still not copy unnecessarily (you can remove the `if not exist` in favor of `/-y` if you prefer the command prompts, but I feel like it just looks messy - especially when it may repeat a really long command every time).

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\"
set "file=file.gitignore"
set "filepath=%dir%\FolderContainingFileIWantCopied\%file%"

for /d %%A in ("%dir%*") do (
    if not exist "%%A\%file%" copy /y "%filepath%" "%%A\%file%"
)
```

Either should accomplish what you want. The important pieces yours is missing are `*` in your `for /d` folder set and that the `%A` (command-line) or `%%A` (batch) at the end needs to also include the name of the file you've copied, which is why I have it written as `%A\file.gitignore` and `%%A\file.gitignore`, respectively (though in the batch it's represented as variables).

> For all subfolders:

For command-line:

```
for /d /r "C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\" %A in (*) do (if not exist "%A\file.gitignore" copy /y "C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\FolderContainingFileIWantCopied\file.gitignore" "%A\file.gitignore")
```

For batch:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\WebDocs\wamp\www\"
set "file=file.gitignore"
set "filepath=%dir%\FolderContainingFileIWantCopied\%file%"

for /d /r "%dir%" %%A in (*) do (
    if not exist "%%A\%file%" copy /y "%filepath%" "%%A\%file%"
)
```

Reference: [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) and [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified." (repeating loop - using batch processing)

Comment: I removed the echo off and it looks like it is going into subfolders `\wamp\www\SubFolder\.git\objects\56` for example

Comment: ah I didn't know how far you needed to dive; I've added the batch for that to my answer and will post the command-line version when I have a chance to.

Comment: added command-line as well; you'll see that the only difference between your initial script was the missing `*` in your `for /d` folder_set and the missing file name at the very end for the `copy` command. the `if not exist` is just personal preference, so as I said in the answer you can remove `if not exist "%A\file.gitignore"` and change the `copy /y` to `copy /`y`.

Comment: Thank you.   The filename is `.gitignore`  there is nothing before the `dot` so I made that small edit and it worked fine.  I want to thank you for your time in doing both the command line and batch file versions of the command, I learned a little today.